# Arguments passing vs. Variable declaration

Tags: c++

What's the difference between passing an argument inside a function as a parameter and declaring the argument as a variable inside the function declaration block in function definition?

Example: Make use of my comments to get the gist of the question.

```
#include<iostream>
         int max=0;
         int t=0;
    class stack
    {
         int s[10];
    public:
         void push(int);
         void pop();
    };
    void stack::push(int y) //argument passed inside function parameter
    {
          if(t<=max);
          {
               s[t]=y;
               t=t+1;
          }
          else
          cout<<"Stack overflow";
    }
    void stack::pop()
    {
         int item; //variable declared inside function definition
         if(t>=0)
         {
               t=t-1;
               item=s[t+1];
         }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking about. Could you give examples in code of the two cases you are referring to?

Comment: What´s the difference of "builing a coin slot of a vending machine which accepts any US dollar coin" and "throwing a coin in"...

Comment: Are you talking about K&R parameter declaration style?  Then why is the question tagged C++?  C++ has never accepted that style.

Comment: Based on the edit, no you aren't... but why are you talking about "declaring the argument as a variable inside the function"?  If it is declared local to the function, it is not an argument at all.

Comment: (Besides that, this code snippet has more bugs than the movie "Starship Troopers")

Comment: Using `#include <iostream.h>` is very ancient C++; it has been `#include <iostream>` since 1998.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the keenness but i still want to know why i should pass arguments(as variables) when i can declare the variables locally in the function...Is there any difference? If not, which is the best practice to use. Your assist is highly valued

Answer (score 0):

One difference is in how arrays are interpreted:

```
// returns nonzero iff array1 equals {1, 2, 3}
int func(int array1[], size_t size1)
{
    int array2[] = {1, 2, 3};
    return size1 == sizeof(array2) && memcmp(array1, array2, size1) == 0;
}
```

While `array2` is an array of 3 integers, `array1` is an array of unknown size, which is why we usually pass a second parameter for the size.  This is because of arrays "decay to pointers" when passed into functions like this.  You can read about it here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

There are fancier techniques for dealing with this in C++ using value templates for the array size, but the above is true of C and most C++ code in the wild too.

Other than arrays, C types used in function parameters behave pretty much the same as C types used in local variables.

Comment: Thank you John. Like a thunderbolt though

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that parameters are initialized by the caller but local variables have to be initialized by the function.

```
int somefunc(int arg)
{
    int local = 0;
    …
    return local + arg;
}
```

When the function is called:

```
int x = somefunc(23);
```

the variable `arg` in the function is initialized with the value 23 by the calling code.  However, the local variable `local` has to be explicitly initialized (in this case with the `= 0`; if it was a class type, by an appropriate constructor).  Local variables of built-in types such as `int` that are not explicitly initialized get a quasi-random value.

Comment: Thank you. Now that is the way to shoulder a newbie. And am correcting the **iostream header too

Answer (score 0):

The arguments is passed by calling that function. so caller decides what should be passed.
functions decides what should it accept.
for example:

```
    main()
    {
        int i=0;
        int k=i;
        for (int j=i; j `enter code here`< n; j++)
        {
        }
    }

is same as
    main()
    {
       int i=0,k;
       
        for (int j=k=i; j < n; j++)
        {
        }
   }
 but this
   main()
    {
       int i=0,k;
       
        for (int j=i; j < n; j++)
        {
           k=i;
        }
   }
is totally different.
```